# Order_by on date using reverse relationship while pushing None values to the end

Tags: django, django-queryset

Using Django 1.7. I'm using a search field on my site where any term linked to a Person object can be searched for.

Here's an extract:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    Q(first_name__icontains=term) |
    Q(last_name__icontains=term) |
    ...
).distinct()[:6]
```

My models (simplified):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    info = models.TextField()
```

**Question**: If multiple persons have the same first name, I'd like order by the most recent comment. If there are no comments for that person then that Person should be at the bottom of the result list.

I tried playing around with `Person.objects.filter(first_name__icontains="i").order_by('-comment__date').distinct()` which seems to work up to a certain extend: if all `Person`s have a `Comment`, then this works OK. 
However if a `Person` doesn't have `Comment`s then they're displayed first (at the top). 
I do want them displayed, but at the bottom of the list.

If this cannot be done in one query, what would be the most effective workaround?

Comment: this will require a rather complex SQL query than I believe the ORM can handle. Try to create the raw SQL first; you maybe able to insert it into the ORM with the `.extra(...)` command.

Comment: here is how i did something similar: `news = news.extra(select={'no_startdate': "CASE WHEN start_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END"}).order_by('no_startdate', '-start_date')`

Comment: @warath-coder: I think that will only work if my `Person` class would have a ForeignKey to `Comment`. At least I get `ProgrammingError: column "comment_id" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT (CASE WHEN comment_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELS...` (similar when doing `comment` instead of `comment_id`). I'm wondering whether Django 1.8's Conditional Expressions might be the way out...